# How can I check to see if an AWS Access key is still being used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have just rotated access keys for a CloudWatch Agent in my AWS account by creating new keys. I have not deactivated the old key yet.

I’ve just noticed that the old key is still being used as in CloudTrail, I see a `DescribeTags` event that uses the old key (with an event source of `ec2.amazonaws.com`).

How can I ensure that the old key isn’t being used anywhere anymore before I can safely remove it?

Comment: You can look in **AWS CloudTrail** to see API calls being made to your service. It will include details of the Access Key being used for those calls.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes i can see the most recent API calls in cloudtrails but i want to get more info as i am unable to get clear picture like which specific resource is using old access key.

Comment: The CloudTrail record will include the IP address of where the request came from. Aside from that, AWS doesn't really know/care which "resource" is making the call -- it's just receiving an API request. The credentials won't be used by an "AWS Service", but they will be used by your own code that is making API calls to AWS.